# How to add Javascript ES6 Polyfill to Typescript in Visual studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, npm

I Want to add

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.findindex

to myfiles.ts in visual studio

I've tried to add

```
/// <reference path="./../../../node_modules/array.prototype.findindex/index.js"/>
```

but array.findIndex unidentified.

Comment: Have you set the compiler `target` to `es6` in your tsconfig?

Comment: @Ramesh I have to use ES5 so it will compatible with IE. That's why i reference the function, findIndex not exists in ES5

Comment: Do you use webpack? or babel?

Comment: If yes - this might be of help https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#loading-polyfills